# Git: Push local files with conflicts to new branch

Tags: git

Say I have 1 branch, **master**, I have cloned it and have since made changes locally that were not merged with the remote **master** branch.

I don't want to just pull from **master** and resolve the merge conflicts, what if I want to compare the differences between the remote branch and my local branch, push the files on my **local** branch that have conflicts to a **new** branch, and then accept all the changes from the **remote** branch.

Is there a way to do this in git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare your local branch against remote master, do:

```
git diff origin/master
```

To push your local changes to a different remote branch, I recommend to first create a new local branch and push that one to the remote server:

```
git checkout -b your_new_branch
git push -u
```

This creates a new local branch and pushes it to the remote server. It also ensures that your local branch follows the remote one if you do a `git pull`.

Finally, to get the changes from master and overwrite your local changes on the master branch, do:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull
```

Comment: Hey mate, cheers for the answer, doing it this way would essentially create a new branch with all the files on my local branch, is there a way to only selectively push files with conflicts to the new branch?

Comment: No, Git is not built around the notion of files, but changesets. Also, branching is cheap and you can later delete a branch if needed.